# Jsoup parsing a Webpage

Tags: javascript, html, jsoup

Is there a quick way to parse a webpage which has multiple forms on it to only get the Code between a specific form tag ?

I would like to only get code which is between the below tags

```
<form name="icaciForm" method="post" action="/waoWeb/icaciSubmit.do">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use selectors. like this:

```
doument.body().select("form[name=icaciForm]")
```